# Webpack HMR module not importing css file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, vite

I have initialized a react app with "Vite". I want to apply a linear-gradient background to all my app but in the browser my app is still a white page. It's like my css file is not imported. When i check the console, there is this message :

GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/src/styles/App.css?t=1681220666642 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

[hmr] failed to reload /src/styles/app.css. this could be due to syntax errors or importing non-existent modules. (see errors above)

here is my code :

main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
<React.StrictMode>
  <App />
</React.StrictMode>,
)
```

App.jsx:

```
import './App.css'

function App() {
  return (
   <div className="app">
    <div className="AppGlass">
      Bonjour
    </div>
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css:

```
.app {
  background: linear-gradient(
    106.37deg,
    #ffe1bc 29.63%,
    #a5070c 51.55%,
    #d30fc9 90.85%,
  );
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "first-dash",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vite build",
  "preview": "vite preview"
},
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
   "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
   "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
   "vite": "^4.2.0"
 }
}
```

and here is the structure of my folders:

[image]

Comment: the problem is with your configuration as i see here /src/styles/app.css your project try to access a css file in styles folder which is not exist, share your config files or create styles folder inside src and put app.css in it

Comment: @mmh4all i have done everything. i created the styles folder and put the app.css in it. Then i removed and changed the path in the app.jsx. I created another css file only to see if it can worki with it. but the problem is bigger than that and i can't find what it is.

Comment: share your vite.config.js and am not sure why webpack is relevant to this question ?

Comment: I really don"t know either. I saw that on google.

Comment: import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'


export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})                                    @mmh4all

Comment: try to create the styles folder and put app.css in it without making changes in app.jsx

Comment: @mmh4all i have an issue. i created the sytles folder and put the app.css in it and in app.jsx, i wrote import './App.css'. if i changed the path in the import like this (import './styles/App.css', the issue disappear. That means there is not a problem with import but the problem comes from the navigator loading app.css file